# Can't find Sass executable file

Tags: ruby, sass, rubygems, phpstorm, executable

I'm using `phpstorm` and I want to use the file watcher plugin with SASS. But I can't find the SASS executable file. It isn't in the path where it should be(I think):

```
C:\Ruby21-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.1.0\gems\sass-3.4.21\bin.
```

There are 3 files but without an file extension.

I already reinstalled SASS a few times but it doesnt help. Does anybody know where the executable file could be? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specified path for sass.bat or scss.bat files locate in :

```
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\sass.bat
```

or

```
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\scss.bat
```

You can read this for more information for PHPStorm Settings : [PHPStorm File Watchers](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/transpiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html)

Comment: Also make sure you are not using the pure js implementation (install via npm). You need to install the standalone version:  https://sass-lang.com/install